# How can I sort images by mdate with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort my images array by modified date to get the names of the last 15 image files modified in "images" directory. 
How can I sort they by date and limit results to 15?

I'm using the following code:

```
<?php 

$extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp'); // image extensions
$result = array();
$directory = new DirectoryIterator('images'); // directory to scan

foreach ($directory as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($fileinfo->getFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if (in_array($extension, $extensions)) {
            $result[] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
        }
    }
}

print_r($result);

?>
```

I've tryed adding this line just before the print_r but it did'nt work:

```
usort($result, create_function('$a,$b', 'return filemtime($b) - filemtime($a);'));
```

And in adittion, I have no idea about how to limit it to the last 15 only.

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Try to pass full path to image. I suppose image name in not enough for `filemtime`

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem seems to be that I was not explicit and the solution was adding `filemtime("/image" . $a)` and `filemtime("/image" . $b)` respectly. All the line looks like this now: `usort($result, create_function('$a,$b', 'return filemtime("images/" . $b) - filemtime("images/" . $a);'));` Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you apparently want the results in an array anyway, I'd do it like this

```
    $allImages = glob(__DIR__ . '/images/*.{jpg,jpeg,gif,png,bmp}', GLOB_BRACE);

    usort($allImages, function($a, $b) { 
        return filemtime($b) - filemtime($a); }
    );

    $topFifteen = array_slice($allImages, 0, 15);
```

This will give you the desired 15 images sorted by MTime.

### Alternatives

If you want to use Iterators at any cost, you can use the following based on the snippet above:

```
$allImages = new ArrayIterator(
    glob(__DIR__ . '/images/*.{jpg,jpeg,gif,png,bmp}', GLOB_BRACE)
);

$allImages->uasort(function($a, $b) {
    return filemtime($b) - filemtime($a); }
);

$topFifteen = new LimitIterator($allImages, 0, 15);

print_r(iterator_to_array($topFifteen));
```

Though you don't gain much from it. In fact, this is likely slower due to the additional method calls involved.

If you want to use the DirectoryIterator/FilesystemIterator at any cost, you could do your own custom Iterator:

```
class LastModifiedIterator extends RegexIterator
{
    public function __construct(FilesystemIterator $filesystemIterator, $pattern)
    {
        parent::__construct(
            $this->sortByMTime($filesystemIterator),
            $pattern
        );
    }
    private function sortByMTime(FilesystemIterator $filesystemIterator)
    {
        $allFiles = iterator_to_array($filesystemIterator);
        $sortedByMTime = new ArrayIterator($allFiles);
        $sortedByMTime->uasort(function(SplFileInfo $a, SplFileInfo $b) {
            return $b->getMTime() - $a->getMTime();
        });

        return $sortedByMTime;
    }
    public function accept()
    {
        return $this->current()->isFile() && parent::accept();
    }
}
```

It does two things:

1. it sorts all the files in the FileSystemIterator by MTime.
2. it filters everything that doesn't match the regex pattern and is not a file

While doing both things in one class might not be the best separation of concerns, I find it okay'ish to do here, unless you need any of the two separately somewhere else.

You can use it like this:

```
$topFifteenIterator = new LimitIterator(
    new LastModifiedIterator(
        new FilesystemIterator(__DIR__ . '/images'),
        '#.*(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$#'
    ),
    0, 15
);

foreach ($topFifteenIterator as $i => $file) {
    echo $file, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Anyways, I'd go with the first one.

Comment: Thank you very much! you are really a PHP master! your reply was very usefull, I sincerely apreciate the time you took for this response.
I didn't use glob because it returns me the entire path and I wanted to get only the file names, but I've learnt a lot reading your examples, much more than only how to order and truncate the results.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the modification date in your array as well, so you can use it for sorting. This way you avoid repeated file access:

```
$extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp'); // image extensions
$result = array();
$directory = new DirectoryIterator('images'); // directory to scan

foreach ($directory as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($fileinfo->getFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if (in_array($extension, $extensions)) {
            // create array elements with two keys:
            $result[] = array(
                "filename" => $fileinfo->getFilename(),
                "modified_on" => $fileinfo->getMTime()
            );
        }
    }
}

// sort function (descending)
function compare_files($a, $b) {
    return $b["modified_on"] - $a["modified_on"]; 
}

// sort files by descending modification date
usort($result, "compare_files");

// keep 15 most recent files
$result = array_slice($result, 0, 15);

// print
foreach ($result as $fileinfo) {
    echo $fileinfo["filename"] . "<br>";    
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly! result very usefull for me to see more than one version about how to do it! I thought adding a "modified_on" variable when I try by my own, but I coudn't make it work, now I got the right way!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to up-vote both answers if you like them :-)